# MAMP on Windows 10 - Apache Server starts and then stops

Tags: apache, mamp

I'm using Windows 10. When I start servers on MAMP, the circle next to Apache Server turns green and then turns white again. MySQL starts as expected. I know Apache Server is starting because I see httpd.exe show up in Resource Monitor on port 8888, but then it grays out and disappears. So, something appears to be stopping Apache Server after it starts. The computer is new and I had McAfee LiveSafe running, but I uninstalled that then rebooted and it didn't fix the problem. I also have Windows Defender, but I allow Apache HTTP Server through the Firewall.

[image: Apache HTTP Server through the Firewall]

Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: Change your port to 8080 or 8081 or some free port, can only thing that 8888 is not free.

Comment: Thanks @maytham-ɯɐɥʇʎɐɯ. If it were a port conflict, I think MAMP would alert me to that. Also, I don't think it would start and then stop. The conflict would stop it from starting at all. But, just in case, I tried changing the ports and that didn't fix it.

Comment: good you clarified, I will try, if can come up with more ideas, then I will get back ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the 4.1.1 version of MAMP for Windows. If you have this same problem, I recommend installing version 4.1 instead. There is no link on their website to that version, but you can get it at https://downloads.mamp.info/MAMP-PRO-WINDOWS/releases/4.1/MAMP_MAMP_PRO_4.1.exe.

Comment: I had the same problem as him, tried your solution, and nonw none of them is starting LOL

Comment: Thanks, I'm running Windows 10 and installing 4.1 worked for me. Before installing 4.1, I tried changing ports and switching to nginx, but that didn't help.